# Set footer height

Tags: fancyhdr

My header logo is about 3,5 x 6cm.
The footer logo is about 3 x 20cm.

The header is shown on the correct place, but the footer is not shown at all. How should I change the geometry so that the footer is shown?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}       % customize page layout
\usepackage{graphicx}       % support for graphics
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % headers and footers

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
    headheight=110pt,
    voffset=100pt,
    footskip=50pt
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}                          % sets page numbering off
\pagestyle{fancy}                               % set the pagestyle to fancy to include headers and footers
\fancyhf{}                                      % clear the header and footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}              % no horizontale ruler under header
\fancyhead[L]{
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
}
\fancyfoot[L]{
    \includegraphics[width=20cm]{footer.jpg}
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your geometry set up is a bit wrong. Margins need to be large given what you have in the header and footer. And `voffset` is causing you trouble.

Try

```
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  headheight=4cm,
  top=5.5cm,
  bottom=4.5cm,
  footskip=4cm
}
```

The headers can be made to overlap by putting them in the centre of the page in a box with zero width.

```
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=6cm]{example-image.jpg}\hspace{14cm}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=20cm]{example-image.jpg}}}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}      % show frame to see what is going on
\usepackage{geometry}       % customize page layout
\usepackage{graphicx}       % support for graphics
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % headers and footers

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  headheight=4cm,
  top=5.5cm,
  bottom=4.5cm,
  footskip=4cm
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}                          % sets page numbering off
\pagestyle{fancy}                               % set the pagestyle to fancy to include headers and footers
\fancyhf{}                                      % clear the header and footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}              % no horizontale ruler under header
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=6cm]{example-image.jpg}\hspace{14cm}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=20cm]{example-image.jpg}}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Tx for your suggestion. And how can I change the geometry settings so that the body text indents more than 5 mm, but the header and footer images remain at 5 mm?

Comment: @user3048741, I updated my answer.